# ¨be given out¨ meaning

Tags: idioms, idiomatic-language

*The cricketer **was given out** leg before wicket.*

**What is the meaning of the idiom ¨ be given out¨ in the sentence above?**

Comment: Do you know the game of cricket at all?  What is the source of your quote. Why are you interested in it?  Have you looked for the "cricket" definition of "out"  in your favourite dictionary.

Comment: I am not interested in Cricket in the least, yet I cannot find the definition in the dictionary.

Comment: @JamesK Hmmm it turns out that you are right. I should have looked for it, so this was a bad question.

Comment: The "unusual" aspect of the cited text isn't to do with the meaning of "Out" as a call in cricket - it's the use of ***given*** to mean ***declared, ruled, classified as***. You won't find it used with that sense in many if any other contexts apart from sports referee decisions. For example, no-one would say *I took my car to the garage but it was **given unrepairable***.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica I agree exactly.  "Given" is the tricky part here, but I wanted to know if terms like "out" or "leg before" were well understood before I answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrase "leg before wicket" seems to be cricket jargon   See:
[Wikipedia "leg before wicket"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leg_before_wicket)
"Leg before wicket (lbw) is one of the ways in which a batter can be dismissed in the sport of cricket. Following an appeal by the fielding side, the umpire may rule a batter out lbw..."

So, "given out" means the batter was ruled "out", or dismissed from batting, and "leg before wicket" is the reason.